# Adding a refresh logo to uisearchbar

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

Is it possible to add in a refresh logo like the one in safari to the uisearchbar on the iPad?
Like the image below?

I have a uisearchbarcontroller and a uitableview. Wondering if its possible to add the arrow like a refresh. Its possible to add in search result and bookmarks.

[image: refresh icon]

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can .. you will need to replace the clear button with a custom button that will make your refresh action .. and here is the code to do that

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = yourSearchBar;
UITextField *searchtextfield = [searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:1];
UIButton *cButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
cButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20 , 20);
cButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[cButton setImage:[UIImage newImageFromResource:@"yourButtonImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];//refresh image.
cButton.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
[cButton addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshButtonPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];//This is the custom event(refresh)
[searchtextfield setRightView:cButton];
[searchtextfield setRightViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
```

enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

For iOS 7, replace:

```
UITextField *searchtextfield = [searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:1];
```

With:

```
UITextField *searchtextfield = [((UIView *)[searchBar.subviews objectAtIndex:0]).subviews lastObject];
```